# Arduino - convert a char to an int

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get an integer value from the ASCII char. I have a code like this:

```
String abc = "ABC";
char b = abc.charAt(1);
int b_ascii_value = ...
```

What should the last line be, in order for me to get the ASCII value of `char b` in `int b_ascii_value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A char is really just a number, which can be seen as a character using the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com). See the [reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Char). The ASCII value you want to get is already in your `char b`.

If you really need an integer, you can use this:

```
int b_ascii_value = b;
```

But a char will probably be enough. *Just use `b` in your calculations*, it already is a number.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @user1832583 I updated my answer.

Comment: I think I just wasted an hour of my time! Thank you so much for this simple solution!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user1832583 that's okay, glad to be of help. Don't forget you can upvote this answer and mark it as accepted.